# Can I use a wifi router to connect a client computer software to another local computer without connecting the router to an internet connection?

Tags: system, wireless, connectivity, centralized

good day, may I ask if anyone knows if it's possible to connect two or three computers through a wifi router? It's hard to put it in one sentence so in detailed explanation, I would be making a software (java) in a main computer (I'll call it the server), another computer would then access the server through a client/server type of setup. Basically the computer (connected to the same wifi hot spot as the server) would access the software on the server either through php/jsp and utilize that software in an office setup wherein all the centralized data on the server is accessible to the connecting computer. I would put in a log-in screen first as standard practice to protect access to the server. I was hoping to ask if this is possible (since it's the same setup as using a LAN/wired connection in an office). If it's possible I'll try to research on how to do it (I heard I'll have to read more on sockets programming for this). If you need more detail on the scenario I would gladly provide it. Thank you for answers in advance.

*my next development goal would be to connect the server through a dial-up modem to connect to a remote computer connected to a dial-up modem as well. I'm trying to avoid internet connectivity to increase security problems and to make it more exclusive. Then maybe connect a couple of android tablets as well that is connected to the server for portability. so that would be around 2-3 computers connected to the server and a few portable tablets accessing the data. it would be great if anyone could point me in the direction for the first few steps on connecting the computer to the servers as well... right now I've already developed a java software that is working but it's only on the server and not connected to any router/computer at the moment.

Thanks again.

Comment: Please take time to read the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) section before you post another question. (Specifically "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)".)

Comment: Ok, sorry I'll do that.

Comment: Modem... That'll be a _thrilling user experience_... You are aware of the fact that it is going to be very slow, right? Not to mention, analog phone lines are vastly the easiest to listen to. So if this is your best take on security, think again... You can't skip **proper** security. Read up on certificates, SSH, using VPNs, and generally IT security. Trying to hide is not secure. It is "Security through obscurity" which does not work.

Comment: well technically I don't need real-time data. just a refresh at certain time intervals so slow speed I think won't be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is all perfectly possible. Your question however is in the wrong exchange. Stackoverflow is more for actual programming issues.

Comment: Lots of things are possible, but some are not worth the effort, or are just too painful to try...